# Pandas - Split column by number of items in cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Row 1', 'Row 2', 'Row 3', 'Row 4'], 
                'Original':['A, B, C, D, E', 'A, B, C', 'A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L', 'A']})
```

and would like to split the original column into multiple columns, but group them in groups of 5, like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Row 1', 'Row 2', 'Row 3', 'Row 4'], 
                'Group 1':['A, B, C, D, E', 'A, B, C', 'A, B, C, D, E', 'A'],
                'Group 2':['', '', 'F, G, H, I, J', ''],
                'Group 3':['', '', 'K, L', '']})
```

I tried doing something like this, but I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do it...

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Row 1', 'Row 2', 'Row 3', 'Row 4'], 
                    'Original':['A, B, C, D, E', 'A, B, C', 'A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L', 'A']})

df2 = df1.join(df1['Original'].str.split(', ', expand=True).add_prefix('Individual '))

df2 = df2.fillna('')

df2['Group 1'] = (df2['Individual 0'] + ', ' +df2['Individual 1'] + ', ' + df2['Individual 2'] + ', ' + df2['Individual 3'] + ', ' + df2['Individual 4'] + ', ').str.strip(', ')
df2['Group 2'] = (df2['Individual 5'] + ', ' +df2['Individual 6'] + ', ' + df2['Individual 7'] + ', ' + df2['Individual 8'] + ', ' + df2['Individual 9'] + ', ').str.strip(', ')
```

Anyone have any suggestions? Maybe some sort of a loop that divides by the max number or items in the original cell?

Please and thank you!

Comment: What is the logic behind the splitting?

Comment: I was thinking of doing some sort of a loop where I count the number of columns that contains 'Individual' and I divide it by 5, and create a new column for every x/5...I don't know... I was definitely making it too complicated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) to sum each 5 columns using [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
df3 = df1['Original'].str.split(',', expand=True).fillna('').add(',')
len_cols = len(df3.columns)
df1[['Name']].join(df3.groupby(np.arange(len_cols) // 5, axis=1)
                      .sum()
                      .stack()
                      .str.rstrip(',')
                      .unstack()
                      .rename(columns=dict(zip(range(len_cols),
                                               range(1, len_cols + 1))))
                      .add_prefix('Group '))
```

---

```
    Name        Group 1         Group 2 Group 3
0  Row 1  A, B, C, D, E                        
1  Row 2        A, B, C                        
2  Row 3  A, B, C, D, E   F, G, H, I, J    K, L
3  Row 4              A
```

Answer (score 2):

using `cumcount` and `explode`

```
s = df1['Original'].str.split(',').explode().reset_index()

s['idx'] = s.groupby(s['index']).cumcount() // 5

m = s.groupby(["index", "idx"])["Original"].agg(",".join).unstack().fillna("")

m.columns = (m.columns + 1).map(lambda x : 'Group ' + str(x))

df2 = pd.concat([df1,m],axis=1).drop('Original',axis=1)

print(df2)

  Name        Group 1         Group 2 Group 3
0  Row 1  A, B, C, D, E                        
1  Row 2        A, B, C                        
2  Row 3  A, B, C, D, E   F, G, H, I, J    K, L
3  Row 4              A
```

Comment: I think expand == True is more accurate so I don't have to use explode, but I also thought something like this at the beginning, good answer

Comment: @musclegeekz don't forget to green tick Ansevs answer :)

Comment: On it! Thanks @Datanovice!